# Sunspot, Solr, order_by, encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I have a set of problems with sunspot and enconding issues when sorting.
The main problem is the use of brazilian words with accents. For example, for a set of names as:

- Alberto
- Ana
- Maria
- Álvaro

The name Álvaro, always appears on the end of the list  after call order_by method.

This is my class setting for the column name:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
 searchable do
   text(:name)
   text(:code)
   string :name_sort do 
     name
   end
 end

 def search(options)
    students = Student.search do 
      fulltext(options[:data])
      order_by :name_sort
    end
    students.results
 end
end
```

Can Anyone help?
Thanks 
Luiz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could try using [transliterate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-transliterate) when indexing

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text(:name)
    text(:code)
    string :name_sort do 
      I18n.transliterate name
    end
  end

  def search(options)
    students = Student.search do 
      fulltext(options[:data])
      order_by :name_sort
    end
    students.results
  end
end
```